# How can I prove that $H_1/N_1 \ncong H_2/N_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I have a non-surjective homomorphism $\phi: H_1 \to H_2$, and $N_1 \unlhd H_1$ and $\phi(N_1) = N_2$. How do I prove that  $H_1/N_1 \ncong H_2/N_2$?

All I have right now is an example that works, but how do I prove this in general? Or does this even hold true, in general? In that case, can anyone help me provide an example for which all the given conditions hold and $H_1/N_1 \cong H_2/N_2$?

Comment: Actually $N_2$ is not even normal in $H_2$ in general, since $\phi$ is non-surjective.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, it can be. And even if it is, my specific example showed me that $H_1/N_1 \ncong H_2/N_2$. That is why I am asking if there is a general proof for this. I wonder if what I am saying even makes sense.

Comment: @HongyiHuang on second thought, I think the general proof can be traced from what you said. Since, $N_2$ is not normal to $H_2$ in general, $H_2/N_2$ is not a quotient group, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that the two quotient groups are isomorphic, which are infinite.

Let $H_1 =G\times\langle a\rangle\times\langle b\rangle\cong G\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, where $G$ be the additive group $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Let $N_1 = G\times\langle a\rangle\times 1\cong G\times\mathbb{Z}$ be a normal subgroup of $H_1$. Hence there is a projection $p$ from $H_1$ to $N_1$. Let $H_2 =G\times\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle\times\langle z\rangle\cong G\times \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $N_2 =G\times\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle\times 1\cong G\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be its normal subgroup.

There is an exercise (6.34) in Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups* that $G\times \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\cong G\times \mathbb{Z}$. So now we define such an isomorphism $\varphi:N_1\to N_2$, since $N_2$ is isomorphic to $G\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $\phi = \varphi\circ p$ is a non-surjective homomorphism, with $\phi(N_1) = \varphi\circ p(N_1) = \varphi(N_1) = N_2$.

However, in this case $H_1/N_1\cong H_2/N_2\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What about the following? $H_1 = \mathbb {Z_6}, H_2 = S_3$ and the map is $f(x) = (123)^{x}$. Then, take $N_1 =$ {$0,2,4$} which is normal to $H_1$, and $f(N_1) =$ {$(123),(132),(1)$} $=N_2$, which is also normal to $H_2$. Then the two quotient groups have cardinality of $2$, and we can define an isomorphism.

Comment: Actually you may define $H_2 = H_1$ and $\phi$ be the quotient homomorphism to the normal subgroup $N_1$, and so $N_2 = N_1$....

Comment: But I think the answer I wrote is another good example anyway.

Comment: Your example is also correct.@Ufomammut

Comment: Yes, so now the question for me is the following: If I have to prove the above question, does it suffice to find an example that does not work, which can basically help me conclude that it is not necessary that $H_1/N_1$ be isomorphic to $H_2/N_2$?

Comment: You can replace $N_2$ in my example by $G\times \langle x\rangle\times 1\times1$, and so $H_1/N_1\cong\mathbb{Z}$, while $H_2/N_2\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. They are not isomorphic.